# SettingFlyout's vertical scrollbar

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a large content needs to be put in SettingFlyout. The problem is SettingFlyout too small for it. How to add vertical scrollbar for it?

Update: Javascript Metro app.

Answer (score 0):

The UX recommendation for that scenario would be to break the settings into multiple flyouts.  You really shouldn't put that many settings into a single window.

If you must do it, then wrap the content in a `ScrollViewer` for XAML or `<div class="ms-scrollview" style="style="height: 100%; width: 300px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: visible;">` for HTML.

Comment: WinJS doesn't have ScrollViewer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx

Comment: I said scrollviewer was for xaml.  I included the html solution as well that works.